# symfony 5 mercure bundle HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request returned

Tags: symfony, mercure

I'm trying to use symfony mercure bundle but it doesn't seem to work even with the example given on the documentation.
here is my code in my controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/test", name="test")
 */
class TestController extends AbstractController
{

    public function __invoke(PublisherInterface $publisher): Response
    {
        $update = new Update(
            '/chat',
            json_encode(['status' => 'OutOfStock'])
        );

        // The Publisher service is an invokable object
        $publisher($update);

        return new Response('published!');
    }

}
```

and this the error i get.

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request returned for "http://localhost:3000/.well-known/mercure".

does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

error image [here](https://scontent.frba4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/p851x315/100881909_137478847911477_2030233497540493312_o.jpg?_nc_cat=100&_nc_sid=07e735&_nc_eui2=AeEP6cgsuQdbfkxfSkUpnWOsosQ4TSzMZfuixDhNLMxl-6bIrexduGM10UiTqYxCg1YrPPSL0Tg2SuCGp71l4bu5&_nc_oc=AQnkRr-rK2QIlMj71YzFake1FhBtK5ScC52RnLUIFvspv5I7wfMi_1DI-9KPq4m1luk&_nc_ht=scontent.frba4-1.fna&_nc_tp=6&oh=80559467b790b77cf1ef4b3c60358f47&oe=5EF64D29)

here is a github link for a [my project](https://github.com/lastlevel48/mercure_symfony.git)

Answer (score 0):

I found ...
there was an error in my environment variable

> MERCURE_PUBLISH_URL = http: // localhost: 3000 / .well-known / mercury

instead of

> MERCURE_PUBLISH_URL = http: // localhost: 3000 //.
>   Well-known / mercury,

one slash too many . 
thank you all